# Time PickerDialog not displaying when editText is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, datetimepicker

I'm trying to build a timePicker dialog in my app. It should pop out when the editText is clicked.

```
    private static String b;
    private TimePick tp;
    tp = new TimePick();
    timeIn1=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText22);
    timeIn1.setOnClickListener(this);

     public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            if (id == R.id.editText22) {
                tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_START_DATE);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
            }
        }


        public static class TimePick extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

            public static final int FLAG_START_DATE = 00;
            private int flag = 00;

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
            }

            public void setFlag(int i) {
                flag = i;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofDay, int minute) {

                if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
                    timeIn1.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                    b = timeIn1.getText().toString();
                }


            }
        }
```

**xml**

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText22"
            android:layout_x="174dp"
            android:layout_y="753dp"/>
```

The `editText` has a value which is retrieved from `SQLite`. Now I want it clickable and pop out timePicker dialog for user to edit. I tried this method, but when it clicked, timePicker does not shows.

Have I missed something ? PLEASE HELP ME...thanks a lot :)

Comment: can you post your xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Add  this into your editText attribute as well

```
android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
android:clickable="true"
```

You need to have `android:clickable="true"` in order to make the editText **clickable**. I hope it helps